# Who wins infinite Hex?

Tags: game-theory, ordinal-numbers

In this game, you start with a square. Alice tries to connect the top side to the bottom side, and Bob tries to connect the left side to the right side, like in [Hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(board_game)). Unlike in Hex, Alice and Bob use points instead of hexagons.

Now you might say that neither Alice nor Bob can win, since it is impossible to form a line using only finitely many points. Not so, for Alice and Bob can move infinitely many times!

In particular, let $S_\alpha$ be the state of the board, where $\alpha$ is an ordinal. Then:

- If $\alpha=0$, then $S_\alpha=\emptyset$.
- If $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal, then Alice adds $(\alpha,p,Alice)$, where $p$ is some point in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ that has not already been played, to $S_{\alpha-1}$, unless $S_{\alpha-1}=[0,1] \times [0,1]$. She can use $S_{\alpha-1}$ to inform her decision (in other words, Alice has a strategy function that given $S_{\alpha-1}$, gives her move). Bob does likewise.
- If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $S_\alpha = \bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}S_\beta$.

We say Alice has won if there for some $\alpha$, there is a path in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, composed of points corresponding to Alice's moves, connecting the top and bottom. Bob wins likewise, (connecting the left and right side of the boards).

Since there are ordinals $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha| > |[0,1]\times[0,1]|$, the board must eventually be filled (in particular, it will happen *before* such an ordinal).

One thing to note is that Alice and Bob cannot *both* win, due to the [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem). On the other hand, it is possible for neither of them to win. In this case, Alice would have no curve connecting the top and bottom, and Bob would have no curve connecting the sides.

My question is:

- Does Alice have a winning strategy? (Bob doesn't, due to a strategy stealing argument.)
- Does Alice or Bob have a drawing strategy (a strategy that guarantees either a win or a draw)? (If Bob does, so does Alice.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{c}$ denote the cardinality of real numbers and let $(C_{\alpha}: \alpha < \mathfrak{c})$ be an enumeration of uncountable closed subsets of the unit square.

Let Bob's strategy be playing a point $q_{\alpha} \in C_{\alpha}$ not already chosen at stage $\alpha$ for $\alpha < \mathfrak{c}$. This is possible since, at stage $\alpha < \mathfrak{c}$, the players could have chosen only less than $\mathfrak{c}$ many points of the set $C_{\alpha}$ which has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. Bob can do whatever he feels like for other ordinals.

Note that the game will proceed at least $\mathfrak{c}$ stages since any curve connecting opposite sides contains $\mathfrak{c}$ many points. Any curve $C$ witnessing the victory of a player would be necessarily of the form $C_{\beta}$ for some $\beta < \mathfrak{c}$ and hence contains the point $q_{\beta}$. Thus Bob guarantees not losing if he plays with this strategy. (Of course, by using this strategy, Alice can guarantee not losing as well.)

Comment: This answer needs AC - I wonder if the ultimate answer depends on choice.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Without AC, then it is possible that neither player can win even if the players are cooperating.  Indeed, a victory for either player gives a well-ordering of a set of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, and it is consistent with ZF that no such well-ordering exists.

Comment: In fact, a well-ordering of $\mathfrak{c}$ is exactly what this answer needs to work, so this shows in ZF that no matter what, neither player has a winning strategy (for rather different reasons, depending on whether a well-ordering of $\mathfrak{c}$ exists!).

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh, that makes perfect sense - I'd missed that the definition itself(!) needs AC. Thank you!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki what if you require Bob to have some sort of "constructive" strategy, so he can't make use of the axiom of choice?

Comment: @PyRulez Good question! Actually, I wanted to ask the same: If an answer can be found (without using the Axion of Choice), then Brouwer's fixed point theorem in separable infinite dimensional spaces could be proved constructively.

Comment: As a nit: shouldn’t it be an enumeration of cardinality c subsets, not uncountable subsets?  Otherwise without the continuum hypothesis some of them might fill up.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving: Closed (indeed, all Borel) subsets of a Polish space have the perfect set property. So for these subsets being uncountable automatically implies being of size continuum.

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't answer the question that was asked, but rather an alternative kind of infinite Hex, played on the infinite hexagonal lattice board as shown below. I am posting it because people interested in infinite Hex might find this question and I would think they might want to know about this natural alternative version of the game.
[image]
The players take turns placing stones on the infinite hexagonal board, and
Red aims to connect lower left to upper right, and Blue on the other diagonal.

In joint work, my student Davide Leonessi and I proved that infinite Hex is a draw.

**Theorem.** Infinite Hex is a draw. Neither player has a winning strategy; both players have draw-or-better strategies.

The work was part of Leonessi's masters thesis for the MSc in the Mathematics and the Foundations of Computer Science at Oxford. You can find our paper at:

- Joel David Hamkins, Davide Leoness, [Infinite Hex is a draw](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.06475), [arxiv:2201.06475](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.06475), 2022.

The main theorem is proved by noticing first that a strategy-stealing argument shows that the second player can have no winning strategy. But the second-player (blue) has a drawing strategy (and hence the first also) by a mirroring strategy as follows:
[image]
Blue will fix a horizontal line (green), and then copy the red plays reflected across that line, shifted by a half square. If Red would have connected to the upper right, then the correspondingly reflected blue play would trap the rest of the line to the right, preventing it from connected to the lower left. So this strategy is draw or better for Blue.

The paper has many other interesting results, including the fact that infinite game values do not arise in infinite Hex in any position. In any position, if Red can force a win in finitely many moves, then there is a uniform bound on the number of moves required.

There is also this related (unanswered!) question concerning the logical complexity of the winning condition in this version of infinite Hex:

[What is the complexity of the winning condition in infinite Hex?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/435565/1946).

Please figure it out and post an answer — I will be grateful

Comment: Almost exactly 20 years ago I tried very hard, with algebraist George Bergman, to find a *definition* of Hex on the hexagonal tessellation of the plane that satisfied the standard Hex theorem (**If all cells are filled, then exactly one player must win**) with rules symmetrical with respect to the two players (except that one player must make the first move), and where any finite ordinal could index the moves. We concluded that there was no such game, to my great disappointment, with one sole exception: If the winner is determined by whoever plays on the very last unfilled cell.

Comment: @DanielAsimov A big section in my paper with Davide is devoted to showing how various natural interpretations of the winning conditions admit various drawn outcomes. The no-infinite-game-values theorem we proved seems related to the claim you make. But meanwhile, we remain unsure of the complexity of the winning condition that we find most natural. Is it even a Borel game? If not, then we don't even know in general whether every position in infinite Hex has a winning strategy for one player or draw-or-better strategies for both.

Comment: Oops, in the comment above I intended "any *countable* ordinal" (not "finite").

Comment: @DanielAsimov Could you clarify exactly what is your claim? Why not the game where whoever plays in cell X wins? Or fix some finite subboard, and although the game takes place on the whole infinite board, declare the winner to be whoever wins that subboard. Aren't these games symmetrical and complete, etc.? If not, I'm not sure what your claim is exactly. Meanwhile, let me add that Davide and I do discuss various alternative winning conditions in our paper. For us, some of the important criteria were translation invariance, no both-players-win situation, and others. Take a look.

Comment: I am not sure at this point what my claim is, exactly, though we were looking at situations where a winner is determined after all hexagons in the tessellation are assigned one color or the other, and I think we excluded situations where a winner could be determined after only finitely many turns.